# T-SQL - Turn table with current page and previous pages into a sequential order per session

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I'm trying to create a table to show the activy per session on a website. 
Should look like something like that

**Prefered table:**

```
+------------+---------+--------------+-----------+
| SessionID  | PageSeq|    Page      | Duration  |
+------------+---------+--------------+-----------+
|          1 |       1 |    Home      |         5 |
|          1 |       2 |    Sales     |        10 |
|          1 |       3 |    Contact   |         9 |
|          2 |       1 |    Sales     |         5 |
|          3 |       1 |    Home      |        30 |
|          3 |       2 |    Sales     |         5 |
+------------+---------+--------------+-----------+
```

Unfortunetly my current dataset doesn't have information about the session_id, but can be deducted based on the time and the path.

**Current table:**

```
+------------------+---------+------------+---------------+----------+
| DATE_HOUR_MINUTE |  Page   | Prev_page  | Total_session | Duration |
+------------------+---------+------------+---------------+----------+
|     201801012020 | Home    | (entrance) |            24 |        5 |
|     201801012020 | Sales   | Home       |            24 |       10 |
|     201801012020 | Contact | Sales      |            24 |        9 |
|     201801012020 | Sales   | (entrance) |             5 |        5 |
|     201801012020 | Home    | (entrance) |            35 |       30 |
|     201801012020 | Sales   | Home       |            35 |        5 |
+------------------+---------+------------+---------------+----------+
```

What is the best way to turn the current table into the prefered table format?

I've tried searching for nested tables, looped tables, haven't found a something related to this problem yet.

Comment: What database system are you using?

Comment: There's no way to reliably identify your sessions; in the data you show, OK, `Duration` summed up equals `Total_Session`, but what if you have two sets with the same `Total_Session`, but a bit different `Durations`, like Home = 4, then Contact = 10 then Salse = 10 (total of 24, same as what you have right now).

Comment: @thewildhealer I'm using Sql-server

Comment: @MarcinJ correct observeration. However in the 'real' dataset I have over 3000 different pages. The chance that someone starts a session at exactly the same time, with the same duration, with the same path is close to 0. (an imperfaction i can deal with)

Comment: This is a complex query and I don't know if it can be done in SQL as you require a dynmic number of joins to get your result. I it were Postgres, I would recomend to play around with functions, but I have no knowledge about SQL Server. EDIT : Well Marcin just proved me wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you can risk sessions starting at the same time with the same duration, should be easy enough to do using a recursive query.

```
;WITH sessionTree AS
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as sessionId
        , 1 AS PageSeq
        , *
     FROM Session
    WHERE PrevPage = '(entrance)'
    UNION ALL
   SELECT prev.sessionId
        , prev.PageSeq + 1
        , next.*
     FROM sessionTree prev
     JOIN Session next 
       ON next.TotalDuration = prev.TotalDuration
      AND next.PrevPage = prev.Page
      AND next.date_hour_minute >= prev.date_hour_minute
)
SELECT * FROM sessionTree
ORDER BY sessionId, PageSeq
```

`sessionId` is generated for each entry with `(entrance)` as `prevPage`, with `PageSeq` = 1. Then in the recursive part visits with the timestamp later than the previous page and with the same duration are joined on `prev.page = next.PrevPage` condition.

[Here's a working example on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1e72e519242cf79d471fa9b3163140aa)